# GlassFish cannot execute create-resources command

Tags: glassfish

At this link http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/resource-creation003.htm shown that we can to create resource follows

```
asadmin create-resources glassfish-resources.xml
```

But if perfom this from command line i have message

```
Command create-resource not found.
Check the entry of command name.

Glassfish Server Open Source Edition 4 (build 89)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
asadmin add-resources glassfish-resources.xml
```

Works fine for me